# typescript types: Second parameter must be of the type of method selected by the first, considering parameters and return of the selected method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to make a method that receives two parameters, methodName and method, the first should only accept names of methods that exist in the class itself, and the second method should only accept functions that receive the same parameters and have the same return as the method selected by the methodName parameter, below is my failed attempt:

```js
type ClassMethodNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

class M {
  val!: string
  fnDat!: (str: string, num: number) => Date
  fnNum!: (num: number) => number
  fnStr!: (str: string) => string

  cheker<
    MethodName extends ClassMethodNames<this>
  >(
    methodName: MethodName,
    method: this[MethodName]
  ) {
    console.log(methodName, method)
  }

  constructor() {
    // Should not produce type error
    this.cheker("fnDat", (str: string, num: number) => new Date)
    this.cheker("fnNum", (num: number) => num)
    this.cheker("fnStr", (str: string) => str)

    // Should produce type error
    this.cheker("val", () => { }) // methodNameError (val is not a method)
    this.cheker("fnDat", () => new Date) // argsError
    this.cheker("fnDat", (str: string, num: number) => null) // returnTypeError
    this.cheker("fnNum", (num: number) => "") // returnTypeError
    this.cheker("fnStr", (str: string) => 10) // returnTypeError
    this.cheker("fnNotExistsInM", () => { }) // methodNameError    
  }
}

//
const m = new M()

// Should not produce type error
m.cheker("fnDat", (str: string, num: number) => new Date)
m.cheker("fnNum", (num: number) => num)
m.cheker("fnStr", (str: string) => str)

// Should produce type error
m.cheker("val", () => { }) // methodNameError (val is not a method)
m.cheker("fnDat", () => new Date) // argsError
m.cheker("fnDat", (str: string, num: number) => null) // returnTypeError
m.cheker("fnNum", (num: number) => "") // returnTypeError
m.cheker("fnStr", (str: string) => 10) // returnTypeError
m.cheker("fnNotExistsInM", () => { }) // methodNameError
```

This current case has two problems, the first is that the method parameter does not consider the parameters of the received function, it only takes into account the return.

and it is not possible to use this method within the class itself.

I gladly accept help lol

Comment: Please [edit] this to ask about a single problem, [not two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366).  If it's the `methodName` issue, that has one answer, if it's the methods-with-too-few-params issue [that's just how TS works](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) and you can't change it.  Which one do you want to focus on here?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking about how to check function **type** compatibility.

JS does not know about the number or type of function parameters, so you cannot check for that at runtime.

Therefore, using type operators is the best solution.  For example:

```
interface A {
    a():any;
    b():any
}
interface B {
    a():any;
    b(x:any):any
}

type Test<X extends object, Y extends object, K extends keyof X> =  
    K extends keyof Y ? X[K] extends Y[K] ? Y[K] extends X[K] ? 
    true : false : false : false;

(null as any as Test<A,B,"a">) satisfies true;
(null as any as Test<A,B,"b">) satisfies true;
// error                       ~~~~~~~~~

// I used 'false' instead of 'never' in the Test definition because of this - 
(null as any as never) satisfies true; // oh :(
```

I did have to use a js runtime `null;` statement per key to generate the error, so it is not pure type-coding, unfortunately.  I wonder if there is a simple way to generate an error without any run type coding at all.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XACgEoAuOEATwG4c8AjYsyrAXy1ElkRQCFNbchUuWoDkDAB5MKw5myxgKABxQAVCAGcwAHgAayCBMggAJhuQB7OgCsICMABpkATQNGIp81dv2nAaTdjM2QAawgKCxhkXQA+ZABeXADDIPMwiKjXAH4xXQBtPwBdQI9g5wLirJcKks9omqqwKABXFBJkeAAbDTaOuG7erp6aLAIQZs7O-HMRaeR1LW1UBx4HACI4NZiiZA04MGANGGBNZCbWmjGJqbgZyjmFnWXVtbotnb2Do5Pzc4gaAD0AIMUCgFigeEhUOhUIAfvCEQisFggcgAJLIZo9EzIADkQwguOQoC0EDgOMieJAEAAbtAiaAzgALNSaMDIEwQY4gYAHCwgcR2OBYlCUsBMw7IAC0yFG40mc1mt2Q1LpUA++0Ox1OfyoyFRFiZyBIBCwQA)